# Statics: What it means if a rope snaps

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, statics

There is a drawbridge that is held up by a hinge attached to a vertical wall on one side, and by a vertical rope on the other side. Say a horse starts walking from the wall towards the rope and at a certain distance from the wall, the rope eventually snaps. What does this mean in terms of physics? I think it means that the net force pushing downward is greater than the net force pushing upwards. Is this the correct conclusion or is there more I can say about it?

Comment: If only the rope is holding that end the drawbridge becomes a lever.

Answer (score 0):

As the horse walks along the bridge it exerts the force of it's weight vertically down on the bridge. This force is counteracted by the tension in the rope holding the bridge up. As the horse approaches the centre of the bridge, where a rope bridge naturally curves to it's minimum, some of the tension opposing the weight of the horse comes from the horizontal piece of rope. This is because the rope is not perfectly flat so there is component of tension component of tension that acts lengthwise along the rope.

This force will gradually fray the rope over time, which if you imagine it on a molecular scale would be the bonds breaking in the atom of the rope due to being tugged. After a certain amount of damage the rope's bonds are not strong enough to withstand the weight of the horse and the rope will find a new equilibrium and snap, usually at it's centre if it has been damaged by natural wear and tear, as this is generally where the most tension is.

Comment: Where did the horizontal rope come from?

Comment: Sorry I was thinking of an old school rickety wooden rope bridge like the one near the dragon's castle in Shrek, not a draw bridge like in the question.

I guess the same principles apply?